# How to match ATC requirements to work in EU?

Tags: air-traffic-control, eu

My Brazilian boyfriend is finally planning to move into the EU zone (he actually got an Italian passport). He would be glad to keep his work as an Air Traffic Controller but despite his 10 years working experience he told me he should start the training all over again.

Can someone point us out the shortest way to match the requirements for EU Standards and/or suggest us where to find this kind of information?

Comment: I edited the title to be more specific. If it does not reflect what you meant, feel free to edit it again (and to edit the description of your question as well to be more specific)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to contact the IT ANSP and ask if they accept applications for ready entry ATCOS: https://www.enav.it/sites/public/en/LavoraConNoi/Traduzione-di-Contatti-n.html

In Germany we have plenty of so called „ready entries“ who applied for a job as ATC in Germany while holding a valid non-EU ATCO license.

After an assesment by our company and - hopefully - signing the contract they participate in some weeks of sim training to learn the procedures of the new sectors. After succesfully completing the sim phase the OJT (on the job training) begins. During something between 6 and 12 months they will train working in real world with a coach and finally take one examination per working position.
That‘s it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. We'll surely follow your suggestion!